# Nuxtjs - relative modules not found although correct paths entered

Tags: css, vue.js, import, sass, nuxt.js

I added all files for template I should use in my Nuxt app (`css, js, images etc.`) into `assets/theme` folder. There is `assets` folder structure:

[image]

Inside `assets/theme/sass/layout/_menu.scss` I have this line:

```
            background-image: url('../../css/images/close.svg');
```

Inside `assets/theme/sass/layout/_main.scss` I have this line:

```js
 @include vendor('background-image', (
    'linear-gradient(to top, #{$overlay}, #{$overlay})',
    'url("../../images/banner.jpg")',
```

It is correct path to svg file (also autocomplete works fine) but when I run app, I get error:

```js
These relative modules were not found:     

* ../../css/images/close.svg in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--9-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--9-oneOf-1-3!./assets/scss/main.scss

* ../../images/banner.jpg in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--9-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--9-oneOf-1-3!./assets/scss/main.scss
```

In `assets/scss/` I have `main.scss` file that is my global file to import all other css, scss etc:

```js
@import '../theme/css/main.css';
@import '../theme/sass/main';
```

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

According to the offical documentation:

> Inside your css files, if you need to reference your  assets
> directory, use ~assets/your_image.png(**without a slash**)

In your case i presume this will work:

```
background-image: url(~assets/theme/css/images/close.svg);
```

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/assets#images

Answer (score 0):

did you solved it?

this works for me:
1. I added `@nuxtjs/style-resources` dependency to project
2. This is part of my nuxt.config.js:

```
css: ['~assets/css/styles.less'],
modules: [
   ['@nuxtjs/style-resources'],
],
styleResources: {
   less: './assets/css/modules/*.less'
},
```